# Does a join as where condition create a crossjoin in the background when using hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, join

Creates this query executed in hibernate a crossjoin in the background?

```
SELECT a, b FROM author a, book b WHERE b.id_author = a.id and b.id = 2
```